# How to write the result of a BigQuery script to a table?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery SQL script like this:

```
DECLARE my_dates STRING;

SET report_dates = (
  SELECT month FROM my_dataset.my_date_able)
);

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE format("""
SELECT * from
( select x,
         y,
         month,
         sum(things) as num_things
  FROM my_dataset.my_data
  GROUP BY 1,2,3
)
PIVOT
(
  sum(num_things) AS s
  FOR month in %s
)
""", my_dates);
```

What I would like to do is find a simple way to execute this script and write the results to another table but I can't figure it out. It seems I might need to create a table from a schema and then insert each call in `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` separately - surely there's something more straightforward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT`  statement:

```
DECLARE my_dates STRING;

SET report_dates = (
  SELECT month FROM my_dataset.my_date_able)
);

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE format("""
CREATE TABLE `<yourproject>.<yourdataset>.<target_table_name>` AS

SELECT * from
( select x,
         y,
         month,
         sum(things) as num_things
  FROM my_dataset.my_data
  GROUP BY 1,2,3
)
PIVOT
(
  sum(num_things) AS s
  FOR month in %s
)
""", my_dates);
```

BigQuery will infer the schema from the source table, create the table at the desired location and fill it the results from the query.